# How node's live server Works?

Tags: node.js

I was using the node's live server by installing it by NPM.
if I am changing something in my files its refreshing my browser. I was searching on the Internet but not able to find it.

I want to know how this NPM package works?
When I hit the CTRL + S for saving in my local file how the browser gets the refreshing hit. 
Does something like socket.io working at backend or something else?

Comment: what package are you referring to? If its a package, just look at the code :/

Answer (score 1):

An example package of what you are describing is [nodemon](https://alligator.io/workflow/nodemon/). Here is a great article I read earlier that explains how it works:
https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-nodemon-in-node-js-70b295c2610c/